# How to handle 404 exception handling in angular 4

Tags: angular

How to handle 404 exception handling in angular 4 (response from service) and show it on html page with popup?

Comment: Have you tried something yourself ?

Comment: My try worked I  used handle error function in catch after response with a promise.

Comment: Add what you have tried to the question, explain what is then your concern and your question will be more interesting for people that way.

Answer (score 8):

any http request receive 3 methods 
data , err and complete 
you can make it using subscribe method

```
serviceRequest.subscrbe(
  data => {
      /// here if the request done with no error
  }, 
  err => {
      /// here the function that you want you can check the status of the 
      ///error
      if(err.status == ...) {
        /// you can check for any status like 404 not found 
      } 
  }, 
  complete => {
      /// and this function will be called if the subscription is done and 
      /// you will not need it here
  }
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also create a global rout for all 404 errors:
write the following code in app.module.ts file:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
.
.
.
{ path: '**', canActivate: [AuthGuard], component: ErrorpageComponent }
]
```